# How long does the bus take to go from Viterbo to Orvieto?

Tags: public-transport, italy, tips-and-tricks

I've found the timetables of COTRAL bus company at [its website](http://servizi.cotralspa.it/Orari). However, I find them difficult to interpret.

From Monday to Saturday, according to these timetables, there are three buses going from Viterbo (Piazza Giordano Bruno) to Orvieto (Piazza Cahen). However, how long does this bus take?

The information called "percorso" is also difficult to interpret. Are these the bus stops from the beginning to the end? Are there additional bus stops not listed there?

Comment: Apparently, from the [“Percorsi e tariffe” page](http://servizi.cotralspa.it/PercorsiTariffe) one can interrogate in a different way the website, getting more detailed answers.

Comment: @DaG: I've tried it, but it seems that it doesn't work very well, at least to me. I've been using some COTRAL buses from Viterbo to several towns these days and the stops the bus actually makes are always some kind of "mystery".

Comment: There might be some on-request stops that only locals are interested in.

Comment: @DaG: Well, it's not exactly that way. For instance, when you walk through Viterbo,  you discover that there are lots of bus stops, some of them near to the city center. But, since there isn't any information on these stops, there is no way to know if a bus does stop there unless this is shown in the "percorso".

Comment: We have found ourselves walking to the bus terminal, which is quite far away from the city center, passing through a certain bus stop and then, once on the bus, finding out that the bus stops at that stop. Anyway, it's not really a problem since we are on holidays, thus we are never on a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, we went there. The bus took about 1 hour and 35-40 minutes to go from Viterbo to Orvieto. We could also check that there are other bus stops in addition to those shown in the timetable under the word "percorso".

Answer (score 1):

Kudos for getting everything right on such an awful design! I add more detail to complete your statements,

[image]

There are 3 buses from *Viterbo* to *Orvieto* in the weekdays and 3 on Saturdays. At the moment they seem exactly the same but it's possible during summer (August) they change the timings, frequency or even the stops for the buses running on Saturdays (that's why they are listed separately).

*Percorso* in Italian means *Route*, and the names you see when you click on each timeslot are the stops.

There are no buses on Sundays and during festivals (public holidays).

Edited in from a comment by @Hatef:
I'm not sure how long it takes but since it goes straightly from Viterbo to Orvieto (approx. 43 km) I guess somewhere between 1 to 1.5 hours - the stops should be only the ones listed there (hence 7 stops).

Comment: Thank you: I already knew what "percorso" means. However, this doesn't answer my question: I don't know neither how long does the bus take to go from Viterbo to Orvieto nor if there are additional stops.